# NSNotificationCenter sender equality criteria

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter

Does NSNotificationCenter use pointer equality or some other criteria (like isEqual: or hash:) to determine whether a notification should be sent to an observer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pointer equality -- it only forwards notifications from the specific object that an observer is observing.